# How to find the definition of a c type like `pthread_t`?

Tags: c, vim, pthreads, manpage

I'd like to see the definition of `pthread_t`, how can I find the definition of `pthread_t`? I know that by `man 3 pthread_create`, I can find the usage of functions. But how to find the definition of a type?
I use vim, can I directly jump to the definition of `pthread_t` in vim?

I know I can open `/usr/include/pthread.h`, but it costs some time to find the definition. How can I directly jump to to the definition of `pthread_t`? Say, use ctags?

Comment: Look into the `.h` file.

Comment: Try `clang -E main.c | grep pthread_t`. Not tested.

Comment: Using an IDE like VSCode is absolutely out of the question?

Comment: Why?  Seriously.  Any type that is documented without its members, such as `pthread_t`, should be considered opaque.  You do not need to know the details to use it, and you should not in any event rely on any details you may discover because they may vary among implementations, and even from one version to another of the same implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working in `C`, you should have something like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

near the top of your buffer and, given Vim's `C`-oriented defaults, it should allow you to do a few things out of the box.

1. You can jump to the header by positioning the cursor on `<pthread.h>` and pressing `gf`. `<C-w>f` does the same thing but in a new window.

   See `:help gf`.
2. You can jump to the first available definition of a macro by positioning the cursor on it and pressing `[<C-d>`. Alternatively, `[d` prints the first available definition in the command-line, `[D` prints all available definitions, and `<C-w>d` jumps to the first available definition in a new window.

   You can also use `:djump`, `:dsearch`, and `:dlist` to the same effect.

   See `:help definition-list`.
3. If what you are looking for is not a macro, like `pthread_t` (a type) or `pthread_cancel()` (a function), you can use the less specialised cousins of the commands above:

   `[<C-i>`, `[I`, `[i`, `<C-w>i`, `:ijump`, :isearch`,` :ilist`, which are documented in the same section.

   There is also the related `:help :psearch`.

Tags are another solution, which requires you to index `/usr/include` recursively and point Vim to the generated `tags` file.

Note that, in this very specific case, there is nothing of value to find.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set `:h 'path'`, so Vim is able to find `pthread.h`. Example code to set `path` from gcc/clang (taken from [my config](https://github.com/matveyt/vimfiles)):

```
" gcc_include([{gcc} [, {force} [, {ft}]]])
" get GCC include dirs
function s:gcc_include(gcc = 'gcc', force = 0, ft = &filetype) abort
    if a:force || !has_key(s:, 'gcc_include_' . a:ft)
        " $INCLUDE
        let s:gcc_include_{a:ft} = split($INCLUDE, has('win32') ? ';' : ':')
        " builtin dirs
        let l:cmd = printf('%s -x%s -v -E -', a:gcc, a:ft is# 'cpp' ? 'c++' : a:ft)
        let l:include = map(systemlist(l:cmd, []), 'trim(v:val)')
        let l:ix1 = match(l:include, '#include <\.\.\.>') + 1
        let l:ix2 = match(l:include, '\.$', l:ix1) - 1
        if l:ix1 <= l:ix2
            let s:gcc_include_{a:ft} += map(l:include[l:ix1 : l:ix2], 'simplify(v:val)')
        endif
    endif
    return s:gcc_include_{a:ft}
endfunction

" :GccInclude[!] [/path/to/gcc]
" set local &path to GCC include dirs
command! -bar -bang -nargs=? -complete=file GccInclude let &l:path = join(['.'] +
    \ s:gcc_include(empty(<q-args>) ? 'gcc' : <q-args>, <bang>0) + [','], ',')
```

While `yourfile.c` is active, run `:GccInclude clang` and make sure `:set path?` shows something meaningful.

After that you can make use of anything under `:h include-search`, for example, move cursor to "pthread_t" and press <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd>.

Note that it's a pure builtin feature, so sometimes Vim may fail to parse C code properly.