# Opening a C library header file in Vim

Tags: c, vim, header-files

Say I'm including a header file in vim while writing a C program, e.g

```
#include <time.h>
```

I have no idea what structures or functions are declared there. How can I jump to that file and open it in Vim? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You have it backward.  You include a header such as `time.h` because you want to use something (function, macro, type, ...) that is documented to be declared there.  That is, you know before adding the `#include` what relevant thing it contains. It is not usual to study a header file itself to discover what is declared within, and it may be very difficult to do so because many headers are complex with conditional compilation directives and liberal use of macros.

Comment: you might have an idea of what's in stdbool.h, stdio.h etc, but you don't know exactly the name of a particular type declared or defined there, for example. What I was looking for was some way to just get an overview of the contents in the header file so that I can quickly check the name of something I want to include but which I might not be remembering the name of. If there was a way to just have the header file pop up in my editor, it would greatly simplify things.

Comment: That's what documentation is for, @Daniel, and docs are often easier to read than the header source, too.  Not to mention that standard library headers don't even have to manifest as actual files at all.  Standard library docs can be found in many places, including https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf.

Comment: yeah, looking at the header file isn't much use, I have to agree, since they're not really presented as you'd hope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, Vim is already wired for C by default so you only have to move the cursor to `<time.h>` and press `gf`, to open the header in the same window or `<C-w>f` to open it in a new window.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67343944/546861) to a similar question that was asked a few hours ago for additional pointers.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
find . -name "time.h"
```

to find the file and then you can copy the path and open it with vim.

But this this won't really help, because its not as structured as you might think it is. To learn more about time.h I would google it. There are several websites explaining structs, functions etc.

For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm